# Website scrolling to the right on certain pages

Tags: css, html

I have created http://amitchauhan.site88.net/EPC%20Website/Website%201/ as you can see on the home page the site fits perfectly without giving excess blank space on the right but on the rest of the pages i get excess space on the right. Can some one help me sort this problem as i dont think there is a problem in the css.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

reolaces the existing CSS declarations for id `address2` with this.

```
#address2 {
  position: absolute;
  /* width: 100%; */
  height: 29px;
  z-index: 3;
  left: 21%;
  top: 1526px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `div` with the id of `address2` is the problem. If you remove the `width: 100%` it will fix this problem

Answer (score 0):

You can fix this by adding `html {overflow-x:hidden;}` to you CSS.

This tells the browser to crop anything out of view that is out of the 100% width on the right or left.

---

Another option is to add `html {width:100%;}` to your CSS.

This tells the browser to move all elements into the 100% visible width. It would eliminate scrolling left or right, but may disposition elements if your site is not responsive.

Hope this helped!